# Show image upload validation errors

Tags: laravel

I can't show validation errors in a form that allows multiple images to be uploaded. It only shows the 'Required' error, but those about the 'maximum size' or 'extensions' allowed don't show them.

Where am I wrong?

**Controller**

```
$request->validate([
    'image' => 'required',
    'image.*' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png|max:2048'
]);
```

**Form**

```
<input type="file" name="image[]" class="form-control 
    @error('image') is-invalid @enderror">
<button type="button" id="btn1" class="btn btn-link btn-icon mt-2">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon" width="24" height="24" 
        viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" 
        stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
        <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
        <circle cx="12" cy="13" r="3" />
        <path d="M5 7h2a2 2 0 0 0 2 -2a1 1 0 0 1 1 -1h2m9 7v7a2 2 0 0 1 -2 2h-14a2 2 0 0 1 -2 -2v-9a2 2 0 0 1 2 -2" />
        <line x1="15" y1="6" x2="21" y2="6" /><line x1="18" y1="3" x2="18" y2="9" />
    </svg>
</button>

@error('image')
<span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
</span>
@enderror
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if there is an error within an input array:

```
@if($errors->has('image.*'))
    <ul>
       @foreach($errors->get('image.*') as $errors)
           @foreach($errors as $error)
               <li>{{ $error }}</li>
           @endforeach
       @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
```

With **`@error`** directive :

```
@error('image.*')
   <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
         <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
   </span>
@enderror
```

Comment: The first method will work, but I haven't tested with `@error` directive. Cause `@error` directive doesn't work here.

Comment: I used your second option With @error directive:, but now it no longer shows the "required" validation

Comment: You need to use 2 at a time. One for `image` and one for `image.*` both are dirrerent validation. So `@error('image')` and `@error('image.*')` is different.

Comment: Perfect, is there a way to merge them into one code? Example: @error('image || image.*')

Comment: I am not sure about that, you can make a try and dont forget to give the result here

Comment: I entered both @error validations ('image')<span class = "invalid-feedback" role = "alert"> <strong> {{$ message}} </strong> </span>@enderror@error ('image. *')<span   </span>@enderror
But the second (so the validation for size and extensions) doesn't work.

Comment: For array, try with the first method , 
Which is  `@if($errors->has('image.*'))……`

Comment: I add some details, I would like that only the first image was mandatory through "required" validation. And all, including the first, had the validations of extension and size.